# Buddypress Group URLs

Tags: buddypress

Buddypress Groups use the following URL format:
http://domain.com/groups/group-name

Where "group-name" is the name of the group.

I would like to be able to access a group using the group's ID.

For example:
http://domain.com/groups/45 OR
http://domain.com/groups/?id=45
Etc.

Any help/advance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why would you need an ID as a slug, but you can change the slug to whatever if you install this plugin: "BuddyPress Edit Group Slug"
hope that helps